# problem with making responsive grid boxes for website

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to make a template for my website
I made 2 columns for menu and one big box in centre as main post. I will use fade javascript for switching between menus

Now I want to make it responsive as:
It be like now on desktop browser
[first photo](https://ibb.co/bJPSTJJ)
and when
user opens this site the columns be a row in top and bottom of the bog box
[second photo](https://ibb.co/5YZG7Dg)

```css
.areaborder{
 width:80%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.angry-grid {
   display: grid;

   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;

   gap: 0px;
   height: 100%;

}

#item-0 {

   background-color: #9afbaf;
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 1;

   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;


}
#item-1 {

   background-color: #9d76da;
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-column-start: 1;

   grid-row-end: 3;
   grid-column-end: 2;
    width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-2 {

   background-color: #68c96d;
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-column-start: 1;

   grid-row-end: 4;
   grid-column-end: 2;
     width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-3 {

   background-color: #67e55b;
   grid-row-start: 4;
   grid-column-start: 1;

   grid-row-end: 5;
   grid-column-end: 2;
     width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-4 {

   background-color: #6edbdb;
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 8;

   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 9;
       width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-5 {

   background-color: #67dd7b;
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-column-start: 8;

   grid-row-end: 3;
   grid-column-end: 9;
    width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-6 {

   background-color: #a79857;
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-column-start: 8;

   grid-row-end: 4;
   grid-column-end: 9;
      width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-7 {

   background-color: #d889e9;
   grid-row-start: 4;
   grid-column-start: 8;

   grid-row-end: 5;
   grid-column-end: 9;
      width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-8 {

   background-color: #d8976f;
   grid-row-start: 5;
   grid-column-start: 8;

   grid-row-end: 6;
   grid-column-end: 9;
      width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-9 {

   background-color: #bb77be;
   grid-row-start: 5;
   grid-column-start: 1;

   grid-row-end: 6;
   grid-column-end: 2;
    width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#item-10 {

   background-color: #9c5ba7;
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 2;

   grid-row-end: 6;
   grid-column-end: 8;
  width:780px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="areaborder">
<div class="angry-grid">
  <div id="item-0">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-2">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-4">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-5">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-6">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-7">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-8">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-9">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-10">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is CSS-grid mandatory ? are you allowed to change the markup ? This could easily be done with flexbox and media queries

Comment: i tried , but i couldnt , can you fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a quick demo using flexbox and media query, there's room for improvements.

The idea is the use of [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property and changing the `flex-direction` in media query

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container * {
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.middle {
  flex: 1;
}

.middle>div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
}

.left>div,
.right>div {
  flex: 1;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left,
  .right {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .middle {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```